# Launching a web page in a different process

Tags: browser

I want to launch the browser in a different process when a particular link is clicked on the page.  When I checked the net I found the following tip: http://www.dslreports.com/faq/3849 . But there we have to change the registry. Is there any simple way of doing this without touching the registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) browser, each new window or tab runs in a separate process.  [Internet Explorer version 8](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/Internet-explorer/beta/default.aspx) will do the same (it's currently in the second beta round).

Earlier versions of IE will run a new window in a separate process if it is launched from, say, the Start menu or the command line, or a link in an email (but not by clicking a link within IE).  I imagine you could create a proxy that the client would run through, which would intercept the links you care about and launch them by running a command line request.  That seems like more trouble than mucking with the registry though (assuming that registry change still works -- looks like your link is from 2002).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible unless you change the client computer setup or software it's running.

Why do you want to do this?